# Use Spring managed bean with @Autowired or class with static method?

Tags: java, spring

I have that method, it's placed in a service class, but i would like to move it in another class, e.g. Utils class. Then, which is the best way to use this method:

```
Utils.check(first, second);
```

or

```
@Autowired
Utils utils;

utils.check(first, second);
```

Method:

```
public static <T> T check(T first, T second) {
    return first == null ? second : first;
}
```

Comment: You should use the first way.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to have such a basic method in a Spring bean. You will never need to mock or intercept a call to such a utility method. It's actually so simple that not defining it and using the code it contains directly would make things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Spring will generate a proxy for your class and possibly wrap your method call into a transaction (since its a `public` method). It would be too much overload for such a simple method, that does´t event make use of any autowired dependencies. Stick to your `Util` class, altough you should give things a meaningful name.

I would recommend an `Args` class for parameter validation, with a method name like `requireNonNullOrElse(T object, T objectIfNull)`, which is essentially just the same as `Optional.ofNullable(object).orElse(objectIfNull)`.

Answer (score 1):

A static method may be a better solution. 
This method would be loaded into memory when this class is used for the first time. so you cannot control the lifecycle.

the @Autowired solution would be easy to use in other cases. For example:
1. If you want to mock this method in a unit test. 
2. If you want to control the lifecycle by spring scope.